# Docker on RPI: phpMyAdmin logging out (?) at login

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, phpmyadmin

So I tried to get a combo of phpMyAdmin and a database (jsurf/rpi-mariadb) running on my raspberry pi.

My Dockerfile looks the following:

```
version: '3.1'

services: 
    php:
        image: php:7.4-apache 
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes: 
            - ./src:/var/www/html/
    
    db:
        build: jsurf/rpi-mariadb
        restart: always
        container_name: db
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        volumes: 
            - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql/
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password_test
            MYSQL_DATABASE: test1
            MYSQL_USER: testuser
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password_lol
            
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        environment:
            PMA_PORT: 3306
            PMA_HOST: db
            MYSQL_USER: testuser
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password_lol
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password_lol
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        links:
            - db:db
        depends_on:
            - db

volumes: 
    db_data:
        driver: local
        name: db_data
```

I've tried multiple database programs (?) like hypriot/rpi-mysql, but nothing seems to work, because when I try to log in into phpMyAdmin I get the following error message:

```
You have been automatically logged out due to an inactivity of 1440 seconds. Once you log in again, you should be able to resume the work where you left off.
```

That confuses me a little because I've never logged in and this message is shown immediately after I hit enter on the log-in form.

BTW If someone can recommend a combo of an administration tool for db's and a database which works on raspberry pis, I would love to hear it. (adminer instead of phpMyAdmin also didn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

So this answer is for anyone who might have the same problem.

There is a problem with the current version of libseccomp in the OS of the raspberry pis. I don't quite know the details, but this results in a conflict with the database.

I tried solving the issue with aminer instead of PHPMyAdmin and stumbled across this [issue](https://github.com/TimWolla/docker-adminer/issues/96#issuecomment-778534000) on GitHub. That's when I first heard of libseccomp. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to upgrade to libseccomp2, till now:

[Here](https://peppe8o.com/create-a-custom-mariadb-container-with-raspberry-pi-and-docker/#comment-4879) you find the original comment.

So, when you have the same problem just type the following into your terminal and upgrade to the version, which is not currently included in the stable version:

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libseccomp/libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb
```